# Which subject does かわいい describe in this example?

Tags: grammar, ambiguous-relative-clauses

> 笑顔が無邪気でかわいい子

Hi.
Does this clause here mean a child with an innocent and cute smile or a cute child with an innocent smile?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This is ambiguous and can be taken both ways. I personally feel "a child with an innocent and cute smile" is slightly more likely because you can say 笑顔が無邪気**な**かわいい子 to unambiguously mean "a cute child with an innocent smile".

Answer (score 0):

無邪気 can be an adjective or noun. Particle で in position after a noun indicates an uncontrollable reason. In this case, this sentence means "a child is cute because of an innocent smile" and you can replace "で" with "から".

Comment: 笑顔が無邪気からかわいい子 is ungrammatical. 笑顔が無邪気だからかわいい子 is not, but it still sounds odd.

Comment: @aguijonazo 
Yes. I meant particle only. Grammar will be changed too.

As for oddness, depends on the context. These are not felt as equal options. Will the child be cute without an innocent smile or not?